# Data Science Project Ideas

Tags: machine-learning, bigdata, dataset

I don't know if this is a right place to ask this question, but a community dedicated to Data Science should be the most appropriate place in my opinion.

I have just started with Data Science and Machine learning. I am looking for long term project ideas which I can work on for like 8 months.

A mix of Data Science and Machine learning would be great.

A project big enough to help me understand the core concepts and also implement them at the same time would be very beneficial.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I would try to analyze and solve one or more of the problems published on **[Kaggle Competitions](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions)**. Note that the competitions are grouped by their expected *complexity*, from `101` (bottom of the list) to `Research` and `Featured` (top of the list). A color-coded vertical band is a *visual guideline* for grouping. You can **assess time** you could spend on a project by **adjusting** the expected *length* of corresponding competition, based on your *skills* and *experience*.

A number of **data science project ideas** can be found by browsing [`Coursolve`](https://www.coursolve.org/browse-needs?query=Data%20Science) webpage.

If you have skills and desire to work on a **real data science project**, focused on **social impacts**, visit [`DataKind`](http://www.datakind.org/projects) projects page. More projects with social impacts focus can be found at [`Data Science for Social Good`](http://dssg.io/projects) webpage.

**Science Project Ideas** page at [`My NASA Data`](http://mynasadata.larc.nasa.gov/804-2) site looks like another place to visit for inspiration.

If you would like to use **open data**, this long list of applications on `Data.gov` can provide you with some interesting *[data science](http://www.data.gov/applications)* project ideas.

Answer (score 6):

Take something from your everyday life. Create predictor of traffic jams in your region, craft personalised music recommender, analyse car market, etc. Choose **real problem** that you **want to solve** - this will not only keep you motivated, but also make you go through the whole development circle from data collection to hypothesis testing.

Comment: Getting the data is often one of the biggest challenge :)

Answer (score 3):

[Introduction to Data Science](https://www.coursera.org/course/datasci) course that is being run on Coursera now includes real-world project assignment where companies post their problems and students are encouraged to solve them. This is done via [coursolve.com](https://www.coursolve.org/) (already mentioned here).

More information [here](https://class.coursera.org/datasci-002/wiki/OptionalRealWorldProject) (you have to be enrolled in the course to see that link)