# Small project ideas for Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, bigdata, data-mining, clustering, algorithms

I need some serious help. I am supposed to implement a project (Non-Existing as of now) for my Machine Learning course. I have no basics in AI or Data mining or Machine learning. I have been searching for a while and unable to find something that i can finish implementing in 3-4 weeks time. It carries a huge chunk of my final marks and no matter how much i try i am unable to understand how it works!
Can the machine learning masters please help me out with this. I need a project suggestion to start with. And i want to know how to proceed after gathering the data set. I am totally blank and running out of time for my graduation :(

Appreciate your suggestions! Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this is well too vague to make a good question. You haven't given any parameters other than be implementable in 3-4 weeks. Add much more detail at least, but I think this is off topic.

Answer (score 3):

Gather million twitter user accounts. Then try to guess their gender based on their avatar, tweets and who they follow.

Answer (score 3):

1. Gather app reviews for single app and try to find out the most important features that you can mine for the app developer
2. try predicting the next word in a sentence based on previous words.Eg. Swiftkey does this.
3. Get questions data from stack overflow and try to predict tags for every post on stack overflow.

Answer (score 3):

[Kaggle](http://www.kaggle.com/competitions) has a bunch of good practice datasets and basic tutorials.

Answer (score 3):

Check **my answer** on the related question here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/843/2452. However, given your situation, you might need to work on something simpler. For this, it might be a good idea to review **recommended literature** in the *open source data science master's curriculum*: http://datasciencemasters.org. Many referenced there sources are free and easily available online. I'm pretty sure that many of these sources contain examples of simple projects that you could (re)implement, extend or otherwise use for your task.